# How do I create a JFrame containing a text box and paint component?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I'm trying to create a program that draws 100 random lines every few seconds. I want to add a text field that allows the user to adjust the amount of time in between each refresh.

However, whenever I try to add any more components to my JFrame, the paintComponent disappears completely. How do I create a window with a text field and a drawing?

This is what I have so far

```
{
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.Timer;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Screensaver extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static void main (String[] args){ //Create Canvas
        JFrame one = new JFrame("ScreenSaver");
        one.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Screensaver f = new Screensaver();
        one.add(f);
        one.setSize(600,600);
        one.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent (Graphics a){
        super.paintComponent(a);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        a.setColor(Color.BLUE); //Outline
        Random rand = new Random();
        Timer time = new Timer(4000, this);
        time.start();
        for(int i =0; i<100; i++){
            int x1 =rand.nextInt(600);
            int y1 =rand.nextInt(600);
            int x2 =rand.nextInt(600);
            int y2 =rand.nextInt(600);
            a.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
one.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
one.add(f, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The default layout manager for a frame is the BorderLayout, so you need to add tomponens to a different area of the layout. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and examples. The tutorial also has examples of other layout managers and will show you how to better design your class.

The tutorial also has a section on `Custom Painting` your should read because you also should set the preferred size of your custom painting panel.

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thank you so much!